# Numpy constantly asks: "How many numbers" when importing numpy

Tags: python, numpy, pycharm

As the title states, every time I try to import numpy in PyCharm, it states `"Enter how many numbers: "`

After I type something in, however, it sorts through a list from 0 to the number that I typed, prints it out, and then gives me a bunch of errors such as

> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Integral'"

I have already tried reinstalling numpy and I have checked and verified that none of my program names are named `numbers.py`, or `main.py`, etc. When I run the program through the terminal I do not get this error. But, when I run it through the PyCharm run box thing, it throws this error.

Comment: Sounds like you are not running the module you think you are.

Comment: You probably created your own file somewhere called `numpy.py`.  Do `import numpy`, then do `print(numpy.__file__)` to see where that file is.

Comment: I'd recommend doing that with `numbers` instead of `numpy`. The `Integral` warning is likely pointing to that as being the root cause.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I do not have a file called numpy.py and have tried using the .__file__ function. It simply returns the site-packages numpy and nothing else. So, I don't think that's the issue.

Comment: @user3613038: As Robert Kern suggested, try doing it with `numbers` instead of `numpy`.